# Issue with AJAX loading a php script, called from an onclick;

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

I have a fairly strong background in HTML, CSS, JavaScript and PHP. Unfortunately when it comes to jQuery and Ajax, I am a bit under qualified to say the least. I do web design at work, but deal mainly with bars, nightclubs (people who favour fancy over performance). I have recently came into a job that requires all of the above, plus it has a mySQL backend which uses PHP.

I have a main page. On this page it contains a table. This table is scrollable meaning that the page itself is only about 750px (normal screen size), but the table can scroll for as long as it needs to (information pulled from the DB). The right most column contains 2 buttons, 1 which is to view the details of that column. This button redirects to another page (input type=submit and PHP handles the redirection), easy. The other button however (input type=button) when clicked (lets say this is associated with item A) is suppose to generate another table on the same page which deals with sub items based on item A. Again at first this wasn't an issue. Simple submit button and PHP checks if that submit button was pressed. Now the issue is that there are so many items in the DB that when the user clicks on the button to view the sub items, the page does a quick refresh which makes the first table (possibly 100's of items long) refresh to the top. My main goal is to just have jQuery or Ajax call an external PHP script that will echo the necessary code in order to "build" the other table in the current html page, without refreshing the top table.

Here is what I have / have tried.

```
<script>

function callAjax() {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.open("POST","test.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();

document.getElementById("divClass3").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}


</script>
```

Also, my code in the html page is as follows (Please advise that I used to have the "test.php" code inside my html file. This worked correctly and for the time being I haven't changed based on my results from my attempts) :

```
<div id="divClass3">
<?php if (sizeof($rows2) > 0) echo'


    <table class="tableClass3">

        <colgroup>
            <col class="fifteenper" />
            <col class="fifteenper" />
            <col class="fifteenper" />
            <col class="fifteenper" />
            <col class="fifteenper" />
            <col class="fifteenper" />
            <col class="tenper" />            
        </colgroup>

        <tbody>
            <tr class="tableRowClass3">

                <th class="tableHeadingClass1">
                    heading1
                </th>

                <th class="tableHeadingClass1">
                    heading2
                </th>

                <th class="tableHeadingClass1">
                    heading3
                </th>

                <th class="tableHeadingClass1">
                    heading4
                </th>

                <th class="tableHeadingClass1">
                    heading5
                </th>

                <th class="tableHeadingClass1">
                    heading6
                </th>

                <th class="tableHeadingClass1">
                    heading7
                </th>    
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


<div class="divClass2">

    <table class="tableClass2">

        <colgroup>
            <col class="fifteenper" />
            <col class="fifteenper" />
            <col class="fifteenper" />
            <col class="fifteenper" />
            <col class="fifteenper" />
            <col class="fifteenper" />
            <col class="tenper" />         
        </colgroup>

        <tbody class="tableBodyClass2">
    '?> 

    <?php if (sizeof($rows2) > 0) {foreach($rows2 as $row2): ?>
            <tr class="tableRowClass2">

                <td class="tableDataClass2">
                    <form method="post"> <?php echo $row2['echo1']; ?> </form> 
                </td>

                <td class="tableDataClass2">
                    <form method="post"> <?php echo $row2['echo2']; ?>  </form>
                </td>

                <td class="tableDataClass2">
                    <form method="post"> <?php echo $row2['echo3']; ?>  </form> 
                </td>

                <td class="tableDataClass2">
                    <form method="post"> <?php echo $row2['echo4']; ?>  </form> 
                </td>

                <td class="tableDataClass2">
                    <form method="post"> <?php echo htmlentities($row2['echo5'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> </form>
                </td>

                <td class="tableDataClass2">
                    <form method="post"> <?php echo htmlentities($row2['echo6'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> </form>
                </td>

                <td class="tableDataClass2">
                    <form method="post"> 
                    <input name="View" type="submit" value="View" />
                    <input name="WorkID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row2['WorkID']; ?>" /> </form>
                </td>

            </tr>
        <?php endforeach;} ?>

    <?php if (sizeof($rows2) > 0) echo'
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>   
    '?>
        </div>
```

And finally this is test.php

```
<?php


        $query2 = "
        SELECT 
            SOMETHING 
        FROM 
            TABLE1 
        INNER JOIN 
            TABLE2 
        ON 
            CAT1=CAT2
        AND
            CAT3 = :CAT4
        ";

        $query_params2 = array( 
            ':CAT4' => $_POST['BUTTON'] 
        );

        try 
        { 
            $stmt2 = $db->prepare($query2); 
            $stmt2->execute($query_params2);        
        }

        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        $rows2 = $stmt2->fetchAll();

?>
```

I appreciate in advance any help given. I am simply posting this so that others can benefit from it too. I have been stuck for a few days with no avail. I have seen similar issues, but nothing matching this so I thought I would give it a try. I thank you very much!

Cheers

Comment: Where is the problem?? Please edit your question with a problem or any error code you are given. StackOverflow is'nt there to do your work for you. We are glad to help if we are given all the information on a given problem.

Comment: Where's the jQuery? If you're using jQuery anyway, why not use $.ajax!

Comment: I see you are trying to do the ajax yourself. However, jQuery makes ajax a laugh! If you don't use jQuery elsewhere on your site, you might consider using [Matt Kruse's Ajax toolbox](http://www.ajaxtoolbox.com/) to minimize the script size.

Comment: 1. The problem occurs when I click on a button (in table 1), I would like an onclick handler to load the ajax function (or jQuery, this is where I wasnt sure what to use!) that will generate the 2nd table (the one posted above) without refreshing the entire page like a submit button would do.

Answer (score 0):

First: the problem with your script is that you're trying immediately set the innerhtml after calling ajax. Ajax requests are Asynchronous (unless you tell them not to be), so they will run on their own time, and whatever you put after the call might execute before or after. But basically unless you tell the ajax call to be synchronous (which pauses the script until you get a response), `xmlhttp.responseText` doesn't mean anything yet. The way you handle an asynchronous request in regular javascript is to specify a callback function through `onreadystatechange`. E.g.

```
function myCallback()
{
   ...
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=myCallback;
xmlhttp.send();
```

you could also do this anonymously with `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { ... };`

Either way, for asynchronous calls, you need that callback. And more specifically, you need to handle the callback when the readystate is specifically `200` (successful return), e.g

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("divClass3").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
};
```

The other option is to make it synchronous, which freezes your javascript until it's loaded (this method is generally not recommended). You could do this by simply changing your `.open` statement to

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","test.php",false);
```

(the last parameter determines whether the call is asynchronous or not (true=async; false=sync)

## jQuery

So that's how you would do it in regular javascript, but since you mentioned it, I would highly recommend using jQuery because it will make your life way easier. Here is your entire ajaxcall function using jQuery:

```
function ajaxcall()
{
    $.post('test.php', function(response) {
        $('#divClass3').html(response);
    });
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions about how this works :)