# Load php file file with ajax onclick, without jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm struggling to find resource wich shows how to load a .php file into a div on a page once certain button is clicked. Almost all search results return jQuery solutions, whereas I first want to try it out with standard JavaScript.

For questions purpose lets say I want to load `example.php` into `#example` div when user clicks `#loadExample` link.

Comment: You have a fairly complete rundown at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239719/issue-with-ajax-loading-a-php-script-called-from-an-onclick?rq=1 as well as others. See the related links to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script>

function yourFunction() {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.open("POST","yourpage.php",true);
  xmlhttp.send();

document.getElementById("yourdiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}


</script>
<div onclick="yourFunction"></div> // or you can use button or hyper link
<div id="yourdiv"></div>
```